# Rails 3 virtual attributes not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with virtual attributes:

```
attr_accessible :published_at

def published_at_text
  I18n.localize(published_at, format: :long_no_day_with_seconds) if published_at
end

def published_at_text=(text)
  self.published_at = Chronic.parse(text)
end
```

This works fine in the unit tests, but does not save when the published_at_text field is changed in the view. I've tried using `attr_accessible :published_at_text`, and adding `published_at_will_change!` to the setter method, but I can't get this to work.

The `development.log` shows that the changed value of published_at_text is being passed in, but adding a call to Rails.logger in the setter seems to indicate that it's not even getting called.

What am I missing here?

Comment: IMHO the I18n logic should be inside the views

Comment: So you'd better make the setter get called first. How do you update attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: the fields for the virtual attribute weren't being passed back as part of the article, so they weren't being shown in the params hash.

Replacing this:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'article_published_at_text', @article.published_at_text, class: 'text_date show_seconds' %>
```

with this:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'article_published_at_text', @article.published_at_text, name: 'article[published_at_text]', class: 'text_date show_seconds' %>
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not provided your controller method that created your object using the params hash, but I can make a guess.

You should call explicity the setter with the parameter passed to the controller.

Then checks if the value gets updated on your model.

Comment: You may provide your unit test code in order for us to check how you are doing the assignment there and why it is not working on your controlle.